# How to setup login? Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

so I started building a website in MVC 4 with a template and everything was going fine. But, I felt that there were a lot of features already added into the template that I didn't understand in the slightest and therefore it was a challenge using some of those features properly. One such feature being the login system.

Now I managed to to setup and talk to my external database without to many hassles, but I was/am at a complete loss on how the template knows the users name and that he is logged in.

So I am trying to recreate/setup the same functionality, but from scratch so I can understand how it actually works. That being said... I am lost!

```
[AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
 {
     try
     {
         var canLogin = Services.Login(model.Username, model.Password);
         var cas = Services.CheckAcountStatus(canLogin.Token);

         if (cas.Payload.Items.Exists(m => !m.IsSynchronized)) RedirectToAction("VerifyPin", "Account", cas.Payload);

         return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyPage");
     }
     catch (CustomException ase)
     {
          ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(ase.Error));
     }

      return View(model);
 }
```

This is what I have thus far.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="MyName" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

A lot of examples have explanations for setting up a database using EF and such, but im afraid that is the equivelant to my external database.

Is a database really needed to know if a user is logged in? or is it more just a cookie?

Beyond this I don't know where to go. If someone could at least point me in a good direction I would appreciate it.

In the end my only real goal is to have an easy way for communication between pages that a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Lets us know if the Request is authenticated
        }
```

A simple answer to: "In the end my only real goal is to have an easy way for communication between pages that a user is logged in."

I would suggest reading about the configuration options for forms authentication in the web.config as well as researching the inner workings of the formsauthentication ticket. MVC also has the Authorize Attribute you can use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: After a little better searching, I have managed to make a new custom Authorize attribute that meets my needs along with FormsAuthentication.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC 4 introduced a new membership provider called SimpleMemberhsip which is very flexible and easy to use. Here is an [article that shows you how to customize SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.ie/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html), which may be the best approach for you instead of trying to build a security framework from scratch that is compatible with ASP.NET forms authentication. Forms authentication relies on cookies to tell if a user is logged in across pages. I do not see anything in your code example that handle the cookies. If you look at the Login method that is generated by the Internet template you will see that the method WebSecurity.Login not only handles authenticating the user, it also handles generation of the cookie.